# Where's my /usr/include/sys directory?

Tags: gcc, c

I recently upgraded from Kubuntu 12.04 to 13.04, a complete reinstall.

Using gcc 4.7.3. I compiled some programs to discover there is no `/usr/include/sys` directory.  That is, `types.h`, `stat.h`, etc, are absent.  They exist in the `include/linux` directory but not `include/sys`.

What's going on?

Comment: What's the error message that GCC prints? Please [edit] the question to provide this and other information related to your problem.

Comment: Do you have build essential installed?

Comment: The couple of programs I have tried compile fine so there is no error message from gcc.  I just can't figure where the header is coming from.  I have an editor that builds references to functions and syscall and the like and it isn't happy that it can't find the directory.

Comment: Yes, build-essential is up to date.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use Ubuntu on 64-bit (I can't text exactly right now on a 32-bit system), then the directory from the question is:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys
```

Now, having this information, you can create symbolic links to those files if you really need them at that location (`/usr/include/sys`) using this on a terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h /usr/include/sys/types.h
sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h /usr/include/sys/stat.h

# ...etc
```

Comment: Yes, 64 bit.  I read something similar elsewhere and it seems like everything is in that directory but I am not certain how the headers are getting included from the "#include sys/stat.h" to the x86_64/sys directory.  Is this some new fangled gcc injection feature?  Off-hand I don't see any symlinks or the like that would (externally) lead to this behavior.

Comment: Looks like we passed each other in the wind.  So the bottom line is that the compiler is doing some magic but I may need to use some symlink hacks to make my editor happy?

Comment: @Duck I just edited my answer before 2 min of your comments :)

Answer (score 6):

install libc6-dev-amd64 if you working on a 64-bit linux.
Type the following command on the ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-amd64
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's check what gcc's default include search path is.  From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6666338/113848), we get this command:

```
gcc -xc -E -v -
```

At the end of the output, I see this on my machine:

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

Notice the second-to-last line. That means that when you compile a C file with `#include <sys/stat.h>`, gcc will look for `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h` before trying `/usr/include/sys/stat.h`, without us having to symlink anything.

Answer (score 1):

the sys directory is a unix/linux system header directory with a lots of system commands.  Different brands/version linux may put it in different places.  The following command can help you:

```
find /usr/include -type d -name sys
On my ubuntu 16 got the two
/usr/include/bsd/sys
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys
```

The first one is home to BSD unix system headers.
The second one is a directory containing Linux 64 bits system heads.

I run into problems with cmake not being able to find the sys/stat.h file.
My temporary solution is to make a symbolic link

```
/user/local/include/sys/stat.h from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h
```

I don't want to pollute the /usr/include directory, and I am only making a link to one particular header file and not the whole sys directory.  I think this is a defect of cmake, so making minimal impact by making only one link. Hope this may help those who are suffering from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since my architecture is amd64 there is no `libc6-dev-amd64`. The package to install is `libc6-dev-i386`.

That fixed the dependency for a CPAN-package.

Comment: _'Since my architecture is amd64 there is no libc6-dev-amd64'_: what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is, that on x86_64 architecture, libraries/kernel/etc. packages have amd64 architecture. So, libc6-dev-amd64 is not available to install. Still the problem persists, some software expect to see /usr/include/sys/.